# How I can change log level of slf4j at run time without restarting my application?

Tags: java, spring, log4j, slf4j

I want to change my log level error to debug at run time.

```
logger.debug("LoggerOne::mylogger debug");
logger.info("LoggerOne::mylogger info");
logger.warn("LoggerOne::mylogger warn");
logger.error("LoggerOne::mylogger error");
```

Comment: I think this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573575/how-to-reload-properties-file-without-rebooting-tomcat

Comment: No I want to change log level.